# using underscore "_" in python iterparse

Tags: python, xml, iterparse

new to Python iterparse, what is the meaning of the underscore "_" in iterparse?

for example:

```
for _, element in ET.iterparse(file_in):
```

Comment: It's not *"in iterparse"*, it's just a target of the assignment.

Comment: ok got it. it is just a throwaway variable